# Python regex: How can I match start of string in a selection?

Tags: python, regex

I want to match some digits preceded by a non-digit or at the start of the string.

As the caret has no special meaning inside brackets I can't use that one, so I checked [the reference](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) and discovered the alternate form `\A`.

However, when I try to use it I get an error:

```
>>> s = '123'
>>> re.findall('[\D\A]\d+', s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: internal: unsupported set operator
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't just use the caret outside the brackets,  like so?  `^[A-Za-z]+?` Also it's not strictly true about carets having no special meaning inside brackets. If a caret is the first character inside brackets, it negates the set of characters inside (says match all except `[^...] `

Comment: "some digits preceded by a non-digit or at the start of the string" - doesn't that mean, all digits?  Just use `\d+`...

Comment: @lzkata: The real use case is more complicated. This is just a simplification.

Comment: i actuly have almost the same problem

<b>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257370/im-trying-to-get-proxies-using-regex-python-out-of-a-web-page</b>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\d)\d+
```

Your problem is that you are using `\A` (a zero width assertion) in a character class, which is for matching a single character. You could write it like `(?:\D|\A)` instead, but a lookbehind is nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Repetition in regular expressions is greedy by default, so using `re.findall()` with the regex `\d+` will get you exactly what you want:

```
re.findall(r'\d+', s)
```

As a side note, you should be using raw strings when writing regular expressions to make sure the backslashes are interpreted properly.

Comment: In this simplified use case, yes. In the real use case where matching the start of the string is really necessary this is not possible. Thanks for the raw strings hint.